# How to reduce execution time in C++ for the following code?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have written this code which has an execution time of 3.664 sec but the time limit is 3 seconds.
The question is this-

N teams participate in a league cricket tournament on Mars, where each
pair of distinct teams plays each other exactly once. Thus, there are a total
of (N × (N­1))/2 matches. An expert has assigned a strength to each team,
a positive integer. Strangely, the Martian crowds love one­sided matches
and the advertising revenue earned from a match is the absolute value of
the difference between the strengths of the two matches. Given the
strengths of the N teams, find the total advertising revenue earned from all
the matches.

**Input format**

Line 1 : A single integer, N.

Line 2 : N space ­separated integers, the strengths of the N teams.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int stren[200000];
    for(int a=0;a<n;a++)
            cin>>stren[a];
    long long rev=0;
    for(int b=0;b<n;b++)
    {
            int pos=b;
            for(int c=pos;c<n;c++)
            {
                    if(stren[pos]>stren[c])
                        rev+=(long long)(stren[pos]-stren[c]);
                    else
                        rev+=(long long)(stren[c]-stren[pos]);
            }
    }
    cout<<rev;
}
```

Can you please give me a solution??

Comment: This question is more appropriate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) since it is about optimizing working code.

Comment: Are there any maximum N?

Comment: Do we know anything about the distributions of strengths?

Comment: Have you actually compiled with optimisations enabled?

Comment: You will have an out of bounds access if the user ever enters any number greater than `200000`

Comment: the range of value of N is 2<=N<=200000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite your loop as:

```
sort(stren);
for(int b=0;b<n;b++)
{
   rev += (2 * b - n + 1) * static_cast<long long>(stren[b]);
}
```

[Live code here](http://ideone.com/QLzJSa)

**Why does it work**
Your loops make all pairs of 2 numbers and add the difference to rev. So in a sorted array, b<sup>th</sup> item is subtracted (n-1-b) times and added b times. Hence the number `2 * b - n + 1`

---

There can be 1 micro optimization that possibly is not needed:

```
sort(stren);
for(int b = 0, m = 1 - n; b < n; b++, m += 2)
{
   rev += m * static_cast<long long>(stren[b]);
}
```

Comment: Wrong, try `stren = {1, 3, 5}`, you get as result `-5`, which is definitly wrong.

Comment: Presorting is an interesting approach. But sorting is expensive in itself. Is it faster?

Comment: @Bathsheba For large number of elements, it should be.

Answer (score 4):

In place of the `if` statement, use

`rev += std::abs(stren[pos]-stren[c]);`

`abs` returns the positive difference between two integers. This will be much quicker than an `if` test and ensuing branching. The `(long long)` cast is also unnecessary although the compiler will probably optimise that out.

There are other optimisations you could make, but this one should do it. If your `abs` function is poorly implemented on your system, you *could* always make use of this fast version for computing the absolute value of `i`:

`(i + (i >> 31)) ^ (i >> 31)` for a 32 bit `int`.

This has no branching at all and would beat even an inline ternary! (But you should use `int32_t` as your data type; if you have 64 bit `int` then you'll need to adjust my formula.) But we are in the realms of micro-optimisation here.

Comment: the abs function is working but when I submit the code, the online compiler gives a compiling error

Comment: And what is that error? I've changed it to `std::abs`, make sure you `#include <cstdlib>`

Comment: for(int c=pos;c<n;c++)
            {
                    rev+=(long long)abs(stren[pos]-stren[c]);
            }

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int b = 0; b < n; b++)
{
    for(int c = b; c < n; c++)
    {
        rev += abs(stren[b]-stren[c]);
    }
}
```

This should give you a speed increase, might be enough.

Comment: Apologies for the formatting, I haven't encountered the less-than problem before.

Comment: Use the `{}` button (or Ctrl-K, or indent by four spaces) to indicate a code block, which prevents `<` being treated as HTML

Comment: I think the first for loop condition should b < n - 1 and second loop initailization should c = b + 1 becase when b == c then abs(stren[b] - stren[c]) is Zero. Please correct me I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting approach might be to collapse down the strengths from an array - if that distribution is pretty small.

So:

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> strengths;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int next;
    cin >> next;
    ++strengths[next];
}
```

This way, we can reduce the number of things we have to sum:

```
long long rev = 0;
for (auto a = strengths.begin(); a != strengths.end(); ++a) {
    for (auto b = std::next(a), b != strengths.end(); ++b) {
        rev += abs(a->first - b->first) * (a->second * b->second);
        //     ^^^^ stren diff ^^^^^^^^   ^^ number of occurences ^^
    }
}
cout << rev;
```

If the strengths tend to be repeated a lot, this could save a lot of cycles.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly we are doing in this problem is: For all combinations of pairs of elements, we are adding up the absolute values of the differences between the elements of the pair. i.e. Consider the sample input

3 10 3 5

Ans (Take only absolute values) = (3-10) + (3-3) + (3-5) + (10-3) + (10-5) + (3-5) = 7 + 0 + 2 + 7 + 5 + 2 = 23

Notice that I have fixed 3, iterated through the remaining elements, found the differences and added them to Ans, then fixed 10, iterated through the remaining elements and so on till the last element

Unfortunately, N(N-1)/2 iterations are required for the above procedure, which wouldn't be ok for the time limit.

Could we better it?

Let's sort the array and repeat this procedure. After sorting, the sample input is now 3 3 5 10

Let's start by fixing the greatest element, 10 and iterating through the array like how we did before (of course, the time complexity is the same)

Ans = (10-3) + (10-3) + (10-5) + (5-3) + (5-3) + (3-3) = 7 + 7 + 5 + 2 + 2 = 23

We could rearrange the above as

Ans = (10)(3)-(3+3+5) + 5(2) - (3+3) + 3(1) - (3)

Notice a pattern? Let's generalize it.

Suppose we have an array of strengths arr[N] of size N indexed from 0

Ans = (arr[N-1])(N-1) - (arr[0] + arr[1] + ... + arr[N-2]) + (arr[N-2])(N-2) - (arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[N-3]) + (arr[N-3])(N-3) - (arr[0] + arr[1] + arr[N-4]) + ... and so on

Right. So let's put this new idea to work. We'll introduce a 'sum' variable. Some basic DP to the rescue.

For i=0 to N-1

sum = sum + arr[i]

Ans = Ans + (arr[i+1]*(i+1)-sum)

That's it, you just have to sort the array and iterate only once through it. Excluding the sorting part, it's down to N iterations from N(N-1)/2, I suppose that's called O(N) time EDIT: That is O(N log N) time overall

Hope it helped!